# scala: Match against function declarations

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in Scala, so probably the solution is easy. However I have been struggling with this for a long time and cannot find where my error is. This is a tentative (not working) version of my code:

```
def fa (a: Int): Int = a
def fb (a: Int): Int = a+1
def fc (a: Int): Int = a+2


def myMatch (f: Int => Int): String = f match {
  case fa => "f is fa"
  case fb => "f is fb"
  case _ => "I dont know f"
}
```

And my test:

```
myMatch(fa)
myMatch(fb)
myMatch(fc)
```

result I want

```
res0: String = f is fa
res1: String = f is fb
res2: String = I dont know f
```

result I obtain:

```
res0: String = f is fa
res1: String = f is fa
res2: String = f is fa
```

Warning:

```
Warning:(7, 9) patterns after a variable pattern cannot match (SLS 8.1.1)
If you intended to match against method fa in class A$A71, you must use backticks, like: case `fa` =>
  case fa => "f is fa"
       ^
Warning:(8, 15) unreachable code due to variable pattern 'fa' on line 11
If you intended to match against method fb in class A$A71, you must use backticks, like: case `fb` =>
  case fb => "f is fb"
             ^
Warning:(9, 14) unreachable code due to variable pattern 'fa' on line 11
  case _ => "I dont know f"
            ^
Warning:(8, 15) unreachable code
  case fb => "f is fb"
             ^
```

I have tried to use the backticks as stated by the warning, but writing something like

```
  case `fa` => "f is fa"
```

leads to

```
Error:(7, 9) stable identifier required, but A$A73.this.fa found.
  case `fa` => "f is fa"
       ^
```

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, the only thing is that fa, fb, and fc are methods, but you can only pattern match on a value, which means you need to use functions instead of methods (functions are values, methods are not).  Rewrite them into functions and it will work as you expect.

```
val fa = (a: Int) => a
val fb = (a: Int) => a+1
val fc = (a: Int) => a+2


def myMatch (f: Int => Int): String = f match {
  case `fa` => "f is fa"
  case `fb` => "f is fb"
  case _ => "I dont know f"
}

myMatch(fa) // f is fa
myMatch(fb) // f is fb
myMatch(fc) // I don't know f
myMatch((a: Int) => a) // I don't know f
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks vary much. In order to convert from method to function, I wrote something like " val funA = fa _" for each, and then did the case on that. I am writing this in case somebody faces the same issue.